# Is there a way to fix this error in prettier, in nuxt / vue environment

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, eslint, prettier

I just ran NPM update on a project that was working fine. Now, I am getting a Prettier "Friendly Error". I'm wondering if ESLint and Prettier are not playing well together in my config.

```
error  Replace `⏎··················Coming·Soon!⏎················` with `Coming·Soon!`
```

I'm not really sure what is going on here, but it looks like it's a formatting issue telling me to add backticks. The errors are on HTML markup that does not even have qoutes on it. It's literally `<span>Coming Soon</span>`.

*.eslintrc.js:*

```js
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    browser: true,
    node: true,
  },
  parserOptions: {
    parser: 'babel-eslint',
  },
  extends: [
    '@nuxtjs',
    'prettier',
    'prettier/vue',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended',
    'plugin:nuxt/recommended',
  ],
  plugins: ['prettier'],
  rules: {},
}
```

*.prettierrc:*

```json
{
  "semi": false,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "htmlWhitespaceSensitivity": "ignore"
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error isn't indicating the backticks. It's telling you the whitespace around `Coming Soon!` should be removed.

The config for [`htmlWhitespaceSensitivity`](https://prettier.io/blog/2018/11/07/1.15.0.html#whitespace-sensitive-formatting) can be confusing:

- `ignore` - HTML whitespace is *insignificant*, so *remove it*
- `strict` - HTML whitespace is *significant*, so *ignore it*

Thus you actually want to use **`strict`**. Configure ESLint as shown below (and restart IDE if using VS Code):

```js
// .eslintrc.js
module.exports = {
  rules: {
    'prettier/prettier': {
      htmlWhitespaceSensitivity: 'strict',
    },
  },
}
```

*Note that `htmlWhitespaceSensitivity` config doesn't seem to have an effect in `.prettierrc`.*